Are all subsets of subspaces, subspaces?
As the title suggests. I'm working on some Lineare Algebra problems and came across this thought. Say you take a subset of a subspace, is that subset still a subspace? Or does it depend

Not all subsets are subspaces, in general. I am not sure what you are asking.

A vector space is a subspace of itself. This would mean that all subsets of a vector space would be subspaces.

No. A vector space is closed, so if you add up two vectors or multiply a vector by a scalar, the resulting vector should also be in the space. In the space $\mathbb{R}^2$, if you take the vectors $S = \{(1,2), (3,4)\}$, since the sum $(4, 6)$ isn't in $S$, $S$ isn't a subspace.
You might be thinking of the subspace generated by vectors; if $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, and $S$ is a set of vectors in $X$, the subspace generated by $S$ is the span of $S$. An example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the subspace generated by the vector $(1,1)$, where the space is simply $\{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

For a subset to be a subspace, it needs to be closed under addition and multiplication by field elements (sometimes called scalars). This is not always the case, so a subset of a subspace need not be a subspace.

Probably the easiest way to see that this is not true is to recognize that the empty set is a subset of every space, but this clearly is not a subspace because it does not contain the zero vector.
A subspace must itself be a vector space in its own right. Therefore it must be closed under addition and scalar multipllication (and therefore it must also contain the zero vector).
